# Bash File Manipulation

Tags: linux, bash

What's the best possible way (one line, preferably using head and tail) to extract lines 3-5 and 11-13 from a file?

This accomplishes the first part, but how can I grab 11-13 without making a mess? xD

```
head -5 some_file | tail -3 > output_file
```

Comment: "preferably using head and tail". [tag:sed] and [tag:awk] are better-suited to this task.

Comment: head opens the file once, | opens 2 more file descriptors and then the output again ... so many fd's for one file. :^)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think `sed` can do that easily `sed -n -e "3,5p" -e "11,13p" some_file > output_file`

The `-n` tells sed not to output each line. the `-e'`s tell sed which parts to print out. Can't see how you do it with head and tail: `head -5` only gives you the first 5 lines, so you can't just pipe that to tail - you need a new command, so looking at something more complex like:

```
head -5 some_file > output_file; tail -3 some_file >> output_file
```

Comment: In this case you can combine the statements: `-e '3,5p; 11,13p'`.

Comment: @John3136 I was reading through your bottom example, why is it wrong to pipe to tail and is there a difference between using a pipe and/or semicolon?

Comment: @Dford.py When you used `head -5` all you get is the first 5 lines of the input file. If you pipe those 5 lines to `tail -3` you will be getting the last 3 lines of that first 5 lines. You may be able to come up with the right combination, but it'll be tricky!

Comment: @John3136: You certainly can pipe arbitrary data to `tail`, it is not necessary to read its input from a file.

Comment: @GregHewgill absolutely, but in the OP's question, he is trying to pipe the results of head into tail.

Comment: @GregHewgill It will work but how are you going to use it to get lines 3 to 5 and 11 to 13 in one pipeline? Its just not a good pattern for this case! `head -5 file | tail -3` don't know about you, but I have to think about that to realize it's giving me lines 3-5

Comment: @John3136: See my answer to this question, it explains how to use parentheses to combine two commands into one pipeline. The `sed` answer is still better for this purpose, but at least you can do it with `head`/`tail`.

Answer (score 6):

In `awk` you could do it like this:

```
awk '(NR>=3 && NR<=5) || (NR>=11 && NR<=15) {print}' some_file >output_file
```

Simplified version as suggested by Glenn Jackman:

```
awk '(NR >= 3 && NR <= 5) || (NR >= 11 && NR <= 15)' some_file >output_file
```

Comment: +1. I like the way this reads a little better (keep the end points of the range on the outside), but it's exactly the same: `(3 <= NR && NR <= 5) || (11 <= NR && NR <= 15)`. Also, the `{print}` body is not necessary, that's the default action.

Comment: I agree on the better readablity. However, had I put that additional whitespace in my original suggestion, the command wouldn't have fit in the text frame, so I traded some readability of the conditions for better readability of the whole command.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is with `sed`

```
sed '1,2d; 6,10d; 14,$d' some_file
```

The bit in quotes are the commands and the semicolon is the command separator.  `1,2d` and `6,10d` deletes lines 1 through 2 and 6 through 10 respectively, and `14,$d` deletes line 14 through to the end of the file.   I have to admit I like alexis' answer better:

```
sed -n '3,5p; 11,13p' some_file
```

if only because it says "print lines 3-5 and 11-13" and nothing else rather than mine which says to delete the lines you don't want.

If you insist on only using `head` and `tail`

```
(head -5 some_file | tail -3; head -13 some_file | tail -3)
```

Comment: I really appreciate showing the differences, I realized that sed was ultimately the best route. Is there a way to only pick one line with sed rather and a range?

Comment: @Dford yes, you can pick one line by just using a single number.  Try `sed -n 3p some_file`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sed -n -e 3,5p -e 11,13p some_file
```

Answer (score 1):

You could combine two pipelines:

```
(head -5 some_file | tail -3; head -13 some_file | tail -3) > output_file
```